# Group theory determine if the group is cyclic

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Determine if the following group is cyclic and write down the generators:

$$\Big(\{0,3,6,9\},+12\Big)$$

Comment: Can you explain what that notation *is*?  What are the elements of this group? What is the operator?  What is is the identity? Etc.

Answer (score 3):

Take each element and check if it is generates the group. If any of them do, then the group is cyclic.